# Java Chromium Embedded Framework (JCEF) save mhtml

Tags: java, chromium, chromium-embedded

Is there a way to save an mhtml/mht file using JCEF?

Or generically with chromium?

I need to save the page in one file.

I suppose it possibile, but I didn't find a way.

**EDIT***

I know that it is possibile using chrome using `flags` but I need to do that using java.

any help is appreciated

Comment: In normal Chromium, there is an option in `chrome://flags` , You might be able to enable this in chromium embedded too.

Comment: @JonasCz I know that, I need using java.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a clue about chromium embedded, so I can't really help :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find this to the official site:

> Chromium/CEF do not support saving in the mhtml format.